# How to join these tables together?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm joining plenty of tables together, I want to count the number city of a company in the company2city table, and at same time link that to a row in the company table and then find out if the endtime is more than now.. The company2city is a many to many table that is linked together with the city table. A company can have many cities, and it is in the company2city table.

```
SELECT COUNT(company2city.cityid) as location, city.city 
FROM company 
INNER JOIN company2city ON company.id = company2city.companyid
INNER JOIN city ON company2city.cityid = city.id AND company.endtime > now()
GROUP BY company2city.cityid
```

That select statement works, but it only select those cities that have an instance in the company2city table and if the company.endtime is more than now(). What I want is to select also all the cities in the city table, and if the company.endtime() > now() failed it will just make the COUNT(company2city.cityid) as location = 0

How can I do such select statement?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that what you want is a Left Join instead of an Inner Join. A left join joins regardless and returns null where it could not make a join.

Try this

```
SELECT COUNT(company2city.cityid) as location, city.city  
FROM city  
LEFT JOIN company2city on city.id = company2city.cityid  
LEFT JOIN company on company.id = company2city.companyid  
where company.endtime > now()  
group by city.city
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't return nulls

Comment: @Kevin I changed the group by statement, please try it now

Comment: You said it wasn't returning nulls. It should be returning 0s as the count where it would be null. That is what you mean, right? It isn't returning 0s it is just return counts that are greater than 0? I am just trying to understand because this is working for me with a similar query.

Comment: yes it is returning the counts that are greater than 0 but the 0's are not being returned..

Comment: im thinking im gonna go for the 2 select statements

Comment: After I initially left my answer I edited my answer to where both the joins were Left joins, you didn't copy it before with the second one being an Inner join did you? That wouldn't return 0s if that was the case. You're just not april foolsing me are you? Haha

Answer (score 1):

I think something along the lines of

```
  SELECT COALESCE (COUNT (company2city.cityid), NULL) AS location, city.city
    FROM company
         LEFT JOIN company2city
            ON company.id = company2city.companyid
         LEFT JOIN city
            ON company2city.cityid = city.id AND company.endtime > now ()
GROUP BY company2city.cityid
```

should work for you.  I've never actually tried the coalece in the select with MYSQL but I know it will work with Oracle. But the key is using Left joins instead of the inner joins.

Comment: The fact that you've never used COALESCE probably explains the way you are using it here, which actually makes no sense. But maybe you meant something different. I would recommend you to explain the idea behind your solution, and someone might suggest the necessary correction.